# Dictionary empties after running program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7.5 and i'm trying to make a simple program that has a username, password, and checks if it exists in a dictionary. If true, it prints welcome + username, and ignores if false.
First: code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
users = {}

with open('C:\\Users\\chef\\Python\\fn.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, users.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(users)

def new_user():
    uname = raw_input("Choose a username: ")
    while 1:
        pwd = raw_input("Choose a password: ")
        check = raw_input("Retype password: ")
        if pwd == check:
            print "Saved."
            users[uname] = pwd
            break
        if uname in users.keys():
            pass

def show_users():
    for unames in users.keys():
        print unames

def login():
    uname = raw_input("Username: ")
    pwd = raw_input("Password: ")
    if uname in users and pwd in users.values():
        print "Welcome, " + uname + "! "

def save():
    f=open('C:\\Users\\chef\\Python\\fn.csv', "wb")
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key, val in users.items():
        w.writerow([key, val])
    f.close()

def read():
        with open('C:\\Users\\chef\\Python\\fn.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, users.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(users)

print "Welcome to Yubin's 'fake' Email server."     
while 1:
    read()
    choice = raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
    if choice == "signup":
        new_user()
    if choice == "login":
        login()
    if choice == "showusers":
        show_users()
    if choice == "logout":
        print "You have successfully logged out."
    if choice == "quit":
        x = raw_input("Are you sure? (y/n) ")
        if x == "y":
            save()
            break
        else:
            pass
    else:
        print "Please sign up, log in or see who have signed up."
```

Problems:

1. When I first "sign up", i can log in perfectly fine. But, after closing the program and running it again, i can't log in. i assume it's because i set the dictionary empty every time i start, but it's supposed to rewrite the contents into the dictionary. i use windows 7 and in the preview, when i rerun the program, the file becomes empty.
2. After i write either login, signup or showusers, it prints the last line,

   "Please sign up, log in or see who have signed up. "

Please i ask for solutions, and thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: I solved problem #2, but #1 still is there.

Comment: One probable solution may be to write the contents of the dictionary to a file , and access it later, At every execution you will only edit the file and never initialize the contents of file to be empty , Does that makes sense ? I am not sure BTW

Comment: i don't really get what you mean, but i write the dictionary to a csv file. what happens is that when i close the program and run it again, the dictionary gets empty, as well as the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as hyades stated, that your read-method overwrites the csv-file instead of reading it. The csv-module offers a reader for this purpose. I have changed your read-method like this to make it work:

```
def read():
    with open('C:\\Users\\chef\\Python\\fn.csv', 'r') as f:
        usersReader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in usersReader:
            if row == []:
                pass
            else:
                users[row[0]] = row[1]
        f.close();
```

You can also remove the "with open..."-code block at the begining of the file (after import and users-declaration).

Answer (score 1):

For Problem 1, might be an issue with the mode of the file. Change it to `wb+`

> Opens a file for both writing and reading in binary format. Overwrites
>   the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not exist,
>   creates a new file for reading and writing.

Problem 2 will be solved if you use `if`..`elif` instead of `if`

Comment: nope, changing it to wb+ didn't work. as for #2, i figured it out by using continue after printing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code above. I use only save and read function. I used read function only once, outside while loop (used 'rb' mode istaed 'wb' mode). I used csv.WriteDict and csv.ReadDict classes [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). to read and save data from users dict. I think You can use shelve or json instead csv, propobly these way will by faster and simply ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
users = {}


'''def write():
    with open('/home/marcin/fn.csv', 'wb+') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, users.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(users)'''

def new_user():
    uname = raw_input("Choose a username: ")
    while 1:
        pwd = raw_input("Choose a password: ")
        check = raw_input("Retype password: ")
        if pwd == check:
            print "Saved."
            users[uname] = pwd
            break
        if uname in users.keys():
            pass

def show_users():
    for unames in users.keys():
        print unames

def login():
    uname = raw_input("Username: ")
    pwd = raw_input("Password: ")
    if uname in users and pwd in users.values():
        print "Welcome, " + uname + "! "

def save():
    with open('/home/marcin/fn.csv', "wb+") as f:
        fieldnames=['user','pwd']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, val in users.items():
            writer.writerow({'user' : key, 'pwd' : val})


def read():
        with open('/home/marcin/fn.csv','rb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
            w = csv.DictReader(f)
            for row in w:
                print row
                users[row['user']]=row['pwd']



def main():
   print "Welcome to Yubin's 'fake' Email server."
   try:               
       read()
   except IOError:
       pass
   while 1:
       choice = raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
       if choice == "signup":
           new_user()
           save()
       if choice == "login":
          login()
       if choice == "showusers":
          show_users()
       if choice == "logout":
          print "You have successfully logged out."
       if choice == "quit":
          x = raw_input("Are you sure? (y/n) ")
          if x == "y":
              save()
              break
          else:
              pass
       else:
          print "Please sign up, log in or see who have signed up."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```